# How to read all child elements with tag names and their value from a xml file?

Tags: javascript, xml, dom

I've a xml file in which I'm storing some HTML content in an element tag called `<body>`. Now I'm trying to read all the HTML content of body tag using XML DOM in JavaScript.

I tried this code:

```
var xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc('QID_627.xml');
var bodytag = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("body");
document.write(bodytag);
```

but it is showing [object HTMLCollection] message on the browser screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Andrew Hare pointed out that getElementsByTagName() always returns an array, so you have to use bodytag[0] to get the element you want. This is correct, but not complete since even when you do that you'll still get an equally useless "[object *ElementName*]" message.

If you're set on using document.write() you can try to serialize out the content of the body tag with

```
 document.write(bodytag[0].innerHTML);
```

Better yet would be directly attaching the source DOM nodes into your destination DOM.

You'd use something like

```
document.getElementById("destinationNodeId").appendChild(bodytag[0]);
```

There may be some issues with attaching DOM nodes from another document that may require you to copy the nodes, or jump through some other hoops to have it work.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc('QID_627.xml');
var bodytags = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("body");
document.write(bodytags[0]);
```

`getElementsByTagName` returns an array of elements (even if just one is found) so you need to subscript the array to retrieve your element.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `document.write(bodytag.toXMLString());`

EDIT: Andrew Hare also points out you need to subscript first. I think you may still need to use the `toXMLString` call as well.